# How to extract files from jar file in application?

Tags: java

I'm a beginner developer in java. Anyone knows a code how to extract some files from jar archive? Let's say I'm making a installer. I want to extract some files from the jar of my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try extracting files like that :

```
File file = new File("myfilename.ext");
if (!file.exists()) {
     InputStream link = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/your-path/resources/myfilename.ext");
     Files.copy(link, file.getAbsoluteFile().toPath()); // copy files where you want
}
```

Comment: very short... great thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The jar is just a zip file that contains all the .class files. Open it with any zip software and you can view and extract all the files.

**Update**

If you want to do unzipping in your Java code. Read this article: http://www.baeldung.com/java-compress-and-uncompress. after unzipping you can do normal file manipulation.

Comment: Yeah i know, but i wan't to do it in Java. Inside of my application that will extract it.

Comment: Ok, that wasn't clear from the question, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may extract files using:

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/mydir/myfile.txt");
```

You may then use File.copy() or another to write the file to disk.

The files are typically stored in the /src/main/resources directory if you're using Maven.